# javascript - link & execute from html

Tags: javascript, html

I have some JS in HTML. It works fine when it's in one page, but as soon as I want to put the JS in separate file it doesn't work.

index.html in

```
<script src="js/pw.js"></script>
```

Later, in the specific place I need the JS to appear:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pw.js"></script>
```

Besides that, I have a separate JS file called `pw.js` which contains this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function TheLogin() {
        console.log("CLICK");
        var password = '123';
        if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
            console.log("IR");
            top.location.href="./file.pdf";
        }
        else {
            console.log("X");
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
});
```

Why isn't the separate file working?

Comment: UM, why is a function wrapped in a document ready method? You will not be able to call TheLogin since it is not global.

Comment: Your JavaScript code doesn't actually *do* anything.  It just defines a function which nothing ever calls.

Comment: *" in the specific place i need js to appear"* What now?

Comment: Assuming you are in chrome/firefox hit f12 and look at the network tab when the page loads. Do you see any errors for the files being brought in? The pages where your linked js "doesn't work" may have different relative paths to the js directory. Look at the console tab. Do you see any errors? What are they? Your function TheLogin() doesn't need to be wrapped in a ready function. Only the code that calls it if you are doing so on load.

Comment: Why do you provide the `<script>` tag twice?

Comment: no errors.

ok, as you already understood 
1. i have no clue how js works :)
2. i need a password-protected file download. and it works when the js in html.

Comment: it works when it is like this 

`<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
     function TheLogin() {
      console.log("CLICK");
      var password = '123';
      if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
       console.log("IR");
         top.location.href="./file.pdf";
      }
      else {
       console.log("X");
         window.location.reload();
          }
      }
    </script>`

Comment: `<div class="button_pw">Enter the password:<a class="button" onclick="TheLogin()"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a><form name="login" style="margin: 0px"><INPUT TYPE="text" autocomplete="off" NAME="pass" size="17" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;"></div></form></div>`

Comment: Everybody can read and bypass your password check if you put it client side, this is something you may want to implement on the server. Additionally, questions must show a minimal understanding of the subject being treated, which doesn't seem the case here, I think this question should be closed.

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia i know that its not super secure and im fine with it. And sorry for not being good with js, i used the script i found online

Comment: @Igors it's not by any means secure :) No problem, it's your right to ask.

Answer (score -1):

i'm sorry. it works when its like this:

`<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
     function TheLogin() {
      console.log("CLICK");
      var password = '123';
      if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
       console.log("IR");
         top.location.href="./file.pdf";
      }
      else {
       console.log("X");
         window.location.reload();
          }
      }
    </script>
<div class="button_pw">Enter the password:<a class="button" onclick="TheLogin()"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a><form name="login" style="margin: 0px"><INPUT TYPE="text" autocomplete="off" NAME="pass" size="17" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;"></div></form></div>`